# Accessing li data on click from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I log/access object data from an ng-repeat? I would like to be able to access each specific firebase object when I click on its *li* element. I have been able to log the entire object, but I need to target just that specific *li*'s data?

```
pomodoro_timer.controller('timer', ['$scope','$interval','$firebaseArray', function ($scope, $interval, $firebaseArray) {

      var ref = new Firebase("https://pomodoro-timer7710.firebaseIO.com/");
      $scope.working = $firebaseArray(ref)

      $scope.addWork = function() {
        if ($scope.newWork == null) {
          WorkInputField.placeholder = "Please enter a job"
        }
        $scope.working.$add({
          name: $scope.newWork,
          startedAt: Date.now(),
          completed: false
        });
        $scope.newWork = "";
      }

        $scope.showTime = function() {
          ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
          }, function (errorObject) {
            console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
          });
        }
```

## HTML

```
      <div id="workInfo">
        <div id="enterWork">
          <form ng-submit="addWork()">
            <input id="WorkInputField" type="text" placeholder="Job to complete" ng-model="newWork"></input>
          </form>
          <h3>Your Work:</h3>
          <ul>
            <li class="workList" ng-repeat="work in working" ng-click="showTime()">          
              {{ work.name }}
              <a href="#" ng-click="working.$remove(work)"><span class="removeWork">Done</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I hope this is enough code, its all that pertains to the problem. When I click on each individual *li* I want to view its key/value pairs. Thanks, I'm trying to wrap my head around Angular and this one's been driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
 <li class="workList" ng-repeat="work in working" ng-click="showTime(work)">   ...</li>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.showTime = function(work) { console.log(work);  }
```

Just read the angular document of ng-repeat and you'll understand how it works.

Comment: Wow, that was easy..lol. It's amazing how you can get in your own way sometimes when you get frustrated. Thanks!